# LED when soldered doesn't work, but when removed it works

Tags: led

I have this kit https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07GRYNV6F/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

soldered everything correctly (checked multiple times, the right element in the right place, the polarities etc)

One LED though acts strangely. When I solder it (correct polarity) it doesn't work. The multi meter connected directly to the two pins (not the solder points, directly to the LED legs) shows a dead LED. However when removed from the circuit, i can confirm with multi-meter that it is good and it lights up.

It is probably a very basic think that i am missing, but i am unable to figure it out. and sorry if I am wasting your time.

any hints on what I could verify or can anyone think of an explanation of why is this happening.

appreciate in advance any help
thanks

Comment: what does "shows a dead LED" mean?

Comment: as if no current is passing trough it. Nothing happens, no light, no readings on the multimeter, no beeps... nothing...

Comment: Do you mean the LED doesn't work when the circuit is powered up and operating, or do you mean you assembled the circuit and tried to test the LED in circuit with your multimeter while the circuit is turned off?

Comment: when circuit is powered up the LED doesn't glow. and when i tried to test the led with the multimeter while the circuit is off it doesn't glow and the multimeter doesn't beep...i put the probs directly on the led

Comment: You can't say "no readings on the multimeter" unless you forgot to turn on the multimeter. Tell us what you were trying to measure (voltage? current?), **exactly** how you connected the probes to the circuit, and **exactly** what was shown on the multimeter display.

Comment: Let me guess: that was a blue LED?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When something doesn't work in a circuit, it is time to do some checks. 
By what you say, you have tested the LED to be working when it is outside of the circuit, which means that then next thing to check is if there is any voltage driving the LED.

With the LED in the circuit measure the voltage at its pins. If the voltage is 0V, then it has to be something with the wiring (or maybe it is not meant to be always on).

A bad connection is quite often the culprit to many headaches.

Comment: sure. So when the circuit is OFF, the voltage should be 0. I tested and it is indeed zero at the LED pins. When the circuit if ON, the voltage there should be 5v. I tested it and it is 0 (zero). The LED itself outside the circuit when probed with the multimeter IS glowing and the multimeter emits a continuus beep sound.

Comment: I agree, that it is most probably a bad connection. trying to find it but everything seems ok. Thanks

Comment: okay, so the next step is to chase the signal that is supposed to light up the LED, all the way to its source, until you find the voltage you expect. It is not clear if the LED is connected through wires or it is soldered directly to a PCB, but the search game is roughly the same. Check the wiring on both  sides of the LED, and check the value of the series resistor. (you might have a resistor with a wrong value)

Comment: Check the contact between the solder itself and the pad or the solder and the next pin exposed past the pad trace. Possibly you have a cold solder joint that needs to be re-soldered.

Answer (score 2):

- Verify with Diode test voltage on board terminals for open cct. If shorted then Diode won't work.
- Beware that soldering within 5mm of the base of LED is against best guidelines
- solder time if > 3s can damage the part by shearing the gold wirebond

  - even 1um invisible gap is enough to open circuit and "may" re-attach by "fluke" when unsoldering.  If so, not repairable or reliable.

5mm LEDs transfer heat to cathode cup holder where wirebond is made to the crystal chip at the rate of 1mm/s thus 5mm lead keep-out zone is used for hand soldering or must be done quickly, < 3s with skill.  Thermal stress can shear the gold whisker wirebond.  ( been there, done that with clients)

[image]

- ignore lead shape, but the idea is do NOT bend leads OR solder within 5mm below epoxy base. The needle-nose pliers suggest one way to stop the heat transfer to cathode and top bond connection. But this is not the only way.  Soldertime  <3s is required.  High thermal gradient stress can induce failures from CTE effects.

Answer (score -3):

As i can see you are new here. First make sure you understand the basics of what ever you are testing.
1) You can test LED by putting your multi meter in continuity test mode (makes a beep sound when to probes are shorted)
You can connect Red probe to Anode of LED and black probe to cathode of LED. It should generally glow.

What your are telling "shows a dead LED" about it does not make any sense.

2) If LED does not work in circuit then make sure if the circuit has internal short. You can check it again by connecting two multi-meter probe at pads where led is soldered (LED removed condition) with continuity test mode.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to this group but i understand the basics,

Comment: 1. I tested it and it doesn't glow

Comment: 2 i did that too and i have a good 5v on the pads

Comment: 1) is bad advice, because OP already tested the LED out of the circuit, and doing a conductivity test *in* the circuit makes no sense. 2) is probably not too helpful either, because a failure mode like that is very unlikely.

Comment: He says it glows when connected to multimeter.